# Do blenders need to be kashered

Tags: halacha, technology, contemporary-halacha, kashering-kosherization, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, do [blenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender) previously used for non kosher foods need to be kashered, or merely washed?  Furthermore, do they need to be kashered if one plans to use it for fleishig and then for milchig afterwards or vice versa?

Comment: Any reason to believe it should be different than a knife?

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2012/03/07/kashering-blender/

Comment: Was the food cold or hot?

Comment: @Dov, hot food and davar charif are both issues which I've seen lema'aseh

Comment: Duchka d'sakina